# Make animation repeat while speeding up upon each repetition?

Tags: android, xml, animation

I'm using an XML animation to simulate an image being flipped vertically:

```
<scale
    android:duration="30"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount="30"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:startOffset="200"
    android:toXScale="0.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />

<translate
    android:duration="30"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount="30"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:startOffset="200"
    android:toXDelta="50%" />
```

The animation above basically shrinks then enlarges and repeats 30 times. I want it so that, as each new animation happens, it gets a little faster. I tried using `@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator`, but it seems like that option only speeds up the actual animation, so I only have the same-paced animation happening 30 times.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can only do this via the Java and not through XML.

You need to create your translation animation in the Java code, and there you can use `yourTranslation.setDuration(1000);` where the `int` is in milliseconds.

So you can put your animation in a `for-loop` that will run 30 times, and use a variable that will increase on each iteration (corresponding to the `i++`) and so will increase your animation speed.